# istream::unget() in C++ doesn't work as I thought

Tags: c++, istream

unget isn't working the way I thought it would... Let me explain myself. As I think, unget takes the last character extracted in the stream and it puts it back in the stream (and ready to be extracted again). Internally, it's decreasing the pointer in the stream buffer (creating the sentry and all that stuff).

But, when I use two unget() one behind the other, it's behaviour get deeply strange. If write something like `hello<bye`, and I use `<` as a delimiter, if I use getline and later two ungets, it returns me hello, and no `o<bye"`. This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#define MAX_CHARS 256

using namespace std;

int main(){

    char cadena[MAX_CHARS];

    cout << "Write something: ";
    cin.getline(cadena, MAX_CHARS, '<');

    cout << endl << "Your first word delimited by < is: " << cadena << endl;

    cin.unget(); //Delimiter (removed by getline) is put back in the stream
    cin.unget(); //!?
    cin >> cadena;

    cout << "Your phrase with 2 ungets done..." << cadena;
    return 0;
}
```

Try with `bye<hello`, then cadena gets `bye` and not `e<hello` I thought that unget works with the last one character each time it's called, what the f*** is happening?

Comment: " I thought that unget works with the last one character each time it's called" — nope, just once.

Comment: Then how does it work? (Thanks to dark falcon for putting correctly < in my post)

Comment: @n.m.: nothing in the stream buffer interface prevents as many putback characters as you want. ... and nothing guarantees that you can putback even one character either! It is entirely up to the stream buffer.

Answer (score 6):

The problem you are observing isn't surprising at all. First off, note that ungetting characters may or may not be supported by the underlying stream buffer. Typically, at least one character of putback is supported. Whether this is actually true and if any more characters are supported is entirely up to the stream buffer.

What happens in your test program is simply that the second `unget()` fails, the stream goes into failure state (i.e., `std::ios_base::failbit` is set) and another attempt to read something just fails. The failed read leave the original buffer unchanged and since it isn't tested (as it should), it looks as if the same string was read twice.

The fundamental reason `std::cin` is likely to support only one character to be put back is that it is synchronized with `stdin` by default. As a result, `std::cin` doesn't do any buffer (causing it to be rather slow as well for that matter). There is a fair chance that you can get better results by no synchronizing with `stdin`:

```
std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
```

This will improve the performance and the likelihood of putting more characters being successful. There is still no guarantee that you can put multiple character (or even just one character) back. If you really need to put back character, you should consider using a filtering stream buffer which supports as many character puthback as you need. In general, tokenizing input doesn't require any characters of putback which is the basic reason that there is only mediocre support: since putback support is bad, you are best off using proper tokenizing which reduces the need to improve putback. Somewhat of a circular argument. Since you can always create your own stream buffer it isn't really harmful, though.

Comment: So it depends totally from the cin implementation that I'm using? Isn't unget an ANSI function for the streams in c++? I'm getting confused.

What is stdin? And why is it synchronized with cin?

Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @Carrascado: `std::istream::unget()` is certainly a standard function which is defined to call `this->rdbuf()->sungetc()` but if you keep digging you'll find that there is no guarantee made that it will be successful for an unknown stream buffer. You can create a stream buffer with controlled putback semantics. `stdin` is C's standard input stream accessed, e.g., using `fgetc(stdin)`. Since C++ builds on top of C it was felt that `std::cin` can't just hijack the standard input, i.e., it will effectively use `stdin` under the hood unless told not to using `std:ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false)`.

Comment: Because unget is defined to call sungetc() in his rdbuf (his stream buffer), it would depend on the implementation made to this stream buffer, doesn't it?

Once again, thanks for the answer.

Comment: Yes. It is possible to create a filtering stream buffer which could make some guarantees about the number of characters which can be put back.

Comment: @DietmarKühl is it sure that unget() in boost filtering stream can be used multiple times(about 4 , 5 times ) with no problem of failbit or any other problems that are faced during calling unget multiple times on std::cin ?

Comment: @mr_beginner: I made absolutely no statement about a Boost library. My statement is solely that the standard C++ library supports the creation of stream buffers which do support `unget()`ting multiple characters. The most likely implementation of such a stream buffer is an adapter to an `std::streambuf`. Such stream buffers are generally called *filtering stream bufffer*. This term was coined long before Boost even started.

Answer (score 2):

The actuall reason for this behaviour is related to the failbits of stream as explained in previous answer. I can provide a work around code that may help you in achieving the results you want.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/iostreams/filtering_stream.hpp>
// compile using g++ -std=c++11 -lboost_iostreams

#define MAX_CHARS 256
using namespace std;

int main(){

    boost::iostreams::filtering_istream cinn(std::cin,0,1);
    char cadena[MAX_CHARS];

    cout << "Write something: ";
    cinn.getline(cadena, MAX_CHARS, '<');

    cout << endl << "Your first word delimited by < is: " << cadena << endl;

    cinn.unget(); //Delimiter (removed by getline) is put back in the stream
    cinn.unget(); //!?
    cinn >> cadena;

    cout << "Your phrase with 2 ungets done..." << cadena;
    return 0;
}
```